# Send a 'net send like' message from a Linux Host to ALL Linux and Windows computers on the network

Tags: linux, networking, windows, messaging

I have a mixed set of computers on my work environment here, comprsed of a few Fedora Workstations, CentOS servers, Windows 2016 servers and Windows 10 Workstations.

Now when I need to update a firewall or switch I normally send out an e-mail with a time and date to execute that. But I would also like to inform everyone still on the network 5 minutes before and at the time of start the execution.
Normally I use the windows tool net send or msg (lately) to shoot out a message with an unmistakable not able to ignore message. Now Myself switched to Fedora as my main driver, and struggle to send out simular messages... I would like to send out 1 message to all Windows and Linux users on the network. Is that possible or if required te make 2 messages 1 for all linux users, and 1 for all windows users fine, but they need to be send to ALL users at once. from my Fedora machine.

Tried smbclient  but always get an error.
Tried linpopup can't get it to work.

are there alternatives?

Comment: Add some detail around what syntax you use, and what error you get when trying to send a message via `smbclient` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be talking about the *Messenger service* of Windows. It has been disabled by default since Windows XP SP2, because it was being abused by spammers. It was replaced with the more restricted `msg.exe` in Windows Vista and Server 2008.

The Messenger service used NetBIOS, which was already being deprecated before the WannaCry worm forced speeding up the deprecation schedule. A modern Windows 10 system will not enable NetBIOS by default, and will by default auto-disable it and SMBv1 if it detects those components are not actively used.

So to sum up, **Microsoft is trying very hard to get rid of those network protocol components the Messenger service depends on.**

The Samba suite still includes support for this old service, but it's not going to be very useful if you have followed the security recommendations and disabled SMBv1 already. `linpopup` is just a GUI on top of this Samba functionality, so it won't help you either.

The `msg.exe` seems to be intended for messages between a Windows Terminal Server and its remote clients only. So it might only work when the client has a RDP connection to the server.

In general, it has been proven over and over again that delivering operating systems in a state that allows them to accept messages from unauthenticated sources and display them to the local user without a definite opt-in mechanism is a Very Bad Idea in the internet of the 21st century. It invites spamming and outright deception of less tech-savvy users.

"That is why we can't have nice things" by default: if you want a broadcast-capable instant messaging solution for your work environment, you'll need to explicitly choose and deploy one that fits your needs.

Linux systems are typically very flexible on their software configurations, and the minimal configurations are getting more and more minimalist, to help the deployment of hosted VMs, containers and other cloud-like solutions. So unless your work environment has explicitly standardized on some kind of messaging service, there will be no guarantee that any arbitrary Linux system will have the software to interface with it. A Linux server running a database or some J2EE software might have no reason to have Samba installed at all, and thus would be fundamentally incapable of receiving Windows Messenger-style messages.

So, for several reasons, there is not, and cannot be, a single messaging system that would be enabled by default and automatically supported by all the operating systems in your mixed set of computers. If you want one, you will need to choose one, set it up, and secure it according to your needs.

If your work environment already includes an instant messaging system, you probably should use that.